# Oracle adding a Column? Can it affect data?

Tags: oracle10g

I can't see why it "would" but I figured i'd check here and ask beforehand.

Lets say I have a Oracle 10g Table and I add a Column to it. It shouldn't affect the data already in that table should it?

I can't see why it would but I figured i'd ask to be sure.

Comment: It does not affect the data already present in the table. 

For your reference : Alter table syntax http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a column to an existing table, then for sure it wont affect your data. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm). But if you use other syntax in alter table, then there might be a problem. For example adding constraints.

Also for eg, **When you modify a TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE column to a DATE column, the fractional seconds and time zone adjustment data is lost**.

Comment: It was just a simple addition of a CHAR column, nothing fancy

Comment: Then don't worry and go ahead. Your column will be added in the last position.